# Pause javascript setInterval when user scrolls up, then restart setInterval when user scrolls back to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, setinterval

Ive been struggling with this issue for a while, I have a chat box that sends messages to a DB using an ajax request. When a new message is sent it scrolls to the bottom of the div. Then I use jquery load function to fetch messages from the DB on a setInterval function. This all works as expected but what if a user wants to scroll up to look at past messages? Currently it doesnt allow it as the set interval auto scrolls back to the bottom. Ive seen plenty of other questions similar but none have worked for my situation.

Here is the HTML -

```
 <div class="dm-cont">
  <div class="dm-body"></div>
</div>
```

Where dm-body holds the messages themselves.

Here is the JS script, the ajax request submits a new message and loads in the messages as it scrolls to the bottom -

```
$(".dm-form").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "chat-data/sub-chat.php"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById("dm-input").value = '';
          $('.dm-body').load('chat-data/get-chat.php);
          $(".dm-body").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
         }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My setInterval function to load in new messages every 2 seconds

```
var reload = setInterval(function () {

    $('.dm-body').load('chat-data/get-chat.php);
    $(".dm-body").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");

}, 2000);
```

If I clear the setInterval on scroll for one it stops all reloads because of the initial scroll, but it would also not restart the setInterval so no new messages would load.

```
$(".dm-body").scroll(function() { //.box is the class of the div
    // clearInterval(reload);
});
```

How could I have it when a user scrolls up at least a certain amount it clears the setInterval, but when the user scrolls back to the bottom it restarts the setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also check if the `.dm-body` div is already scrolled down and make the `.load(...)` conditional.

```
var reload = setInterval(function () {
    var dmBody = $('.dm-body');

    // div is scrolled completly when scrollTop is equal scrollHeight - clientHeight
    // so we only load new content when we cant scroll down
    if ( dmBody[0].scrollTop === ( dmBody[0].scrollHeight - dmBody[0].clientHeight ) ) {
      dmBody.load('chat-data/get-chat.php');
      dmBody.animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, 'slow');
    }

}, 2000);
```